# print array in struct in alphabetical order and in descending order

Tags: swift, sorting, struct, swift3

I would like my struct to print its entries in alphabetical order first, then arrange the data in descending order. So the final result would be: "lukes 9", "lukes 4", "smiths 4"

```
struct MyData {
    var company = String()
    var score: Int
}

let data = [
    MyData(company: "smiths", score: 4 ),
    MyData(company: "lukes", score: 4),
    MyData(company: "lukes", score: 9)
]
```

Comment: you need to make your MyData conform to `Comparable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 2 ways you can do this. Both would require you to pass your array to `sort` (Swift 2), now `sorted` (Swift 3).

1. A very easy implementation:

   ```
   struct MyData {
       var company = String()
       var score: Int
   }

   let data = [
       MyData(company: "smiths", score: 4),
       MyData(company: "lukes", score: 4),
       MyData(company: "lukes", score: 9)
   ]

   let sortedArray = data.sorted(by: { ($0.company, $1.score) < ($1.company, $0.score) })
   ```
2. You could also make `MyData` conform to `Comparable`. This keeps the comparison logic within the MyData type, and you can just run the `sorted()` function to return a new array:

   ```
   struct MyData {
       var company = String()
       var score: Int
   }

   extension MyData: Equatable {
       static func ==(lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
           return (lhs.company, lhs.score) == (rhs.company, rhs.score)
       }
   }

   extension MyData: Comparable {
        static func <(lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
           return (rhs.company, lhs.score) > (lhs.company, rhs.score)
       }
   }  

   let data = [
       MyData(company: "smiths", score: 4),
       MyData(company: "lukes", score: 4),
       MyData(company: "lukes", score: 9)
   ]

   let sortedArray = data.sorted()
   ```

These 2 implementations both output your desired result: "lukes 9", "lukes 4", "smiths 4"

Comment: To read more about the static methods for equality and comparison check out [Apple's documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9cf2685293108ea3efcbebb7ee6a8618b83d4a90/proposals/0091-improving-operators-in-protocols.md)