# Ordering two string variables alphabetically in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, swift3

I have two string variables:`var myName` and `var friendsName`. They are both strings and I want to sort them alphabetically. When I put them into an array like this `var nameArray = [myName, friendsName]` and then try to sort it by doing `nameArray.sort()` - I get an error telling me that I need to use the by predicate.

How would I order these strings alphabetically if swift isnt recognizing them as comparable?

Comment: That should work. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

So, in Swift3, you can do `nameArray.sorted()` or `nameArray.sort()`

You can get around making them comparable by simply doing this: `nameArray = nameArray.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })` or `nameArray.sort(by: <)`.

Examples:

- .sorted

  ```
  var nameArray = ["Tommy", "Anoop", "Jerry"]
  nameArray = nameArray.sorted(by: { $1 > $0 })
  print(nameArray)
  ```
- .sort

  ```
  var nameArray = ["Tommy", "Anoop", "Jerry"]
  nameArray.sort(by: <)
  print(nameArray)
  ```

Output: `["Anoop", "Jerry", "Tommy"]`

Comment: You can also reference my in-depth sorting answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019062/print-array-in-struct-in-alphabetical-order-and-in-descending-order/46019344#46019344)

Comment: There is `sort()` in Swift 3, to sort an array in-place.

Comment: @MartinR yes you're right. I just looked at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort).

Comment: Edited my post to add `sort()`, hope this helps!

Comment: `nameArray.sort()` as in the question would work as well. The problem is that there is no clear reproducible problem description in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error that, for example, will be thrown if one of the strings is nil. One thing you might try to catch this in a clearer way is to declare nameArray as an array of Strings.

```
var nameArray: [String] = [myname, friendsName]
```

You'll get a different error if one of the strings is not a string at all.